# Connection at client database hangs application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sqlconnection

On my application I need to connect at client database(SqlServer) only to see if we can  connect.
These are my connection strings from web.config(the values are not that way, I´ve changed the ip, user and pwd)

```
<add name="ConnectionStringLibracom" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.1.45\SqlServer2008;Initial Catalog=xxx;user=xxx;pwd=xxx;Application Name=MES"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> (MINE)
<add name="ConnectionStringMigplus" connectionString="Data Source=999.99.999.99;Initial Catalog=xxx;user=xxx;pwd=xxx"
          providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> (CLIENT)
```

but this piece of code hangs my entire application(when I say that it hangs, I mean that it dont let my application to connect to our DB). I´m executing it at Default.aspx on Load event:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!TestaIntegracaoErpMigplus())
    {
        lblMensagemIntegracao.Visible = true;
        Session["Integracao"] = false;
    }
    else
        Session["Integracao"] = true;
}

protected static bool TestaIntegracaoErpMigplus()
{
    string connectionStringMigplus = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringMigplus"].ConnectionString;
    bool ret = false;

    using (SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(connectionStringMigplus))
    {
        try
        {
            Conn.Open();
            if (Conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                ret = true;
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            ret = false;
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

@EDIT: The problem is not if I can connect to the server or not, the problem is: when I´m trying to connect to that db my asp.net website frozen to new requests at others page

Comment: Well catching the exception in that way is really a bad practice. How do you know what error the connection attempt is throwing at you?

Comment: Log the exception you're catching - there will be some info why you can't connect to the database.

Comment: on this method I´m assuming that: if it throw any kind of exception then I could not connect... but this doesn´t seem the problem that I pointed out with my question, sorry being rude.

Comment: I will edit my question, maybe it is not well explained.

Comment: @EDIT: The problem is not if I can connect to the server or not, the problem is: when I´m trying to connect to that db my asp.net website frozen to new requests at others page

Comment: you can try move connection to `Task` and use `Wait` function with timeout

Comment: @Marciano.Andrade One question it may sound stupid, when you say new request to other pages, Does that mean those pages were active when you try to connect with your Client's connection string ? Can you provide any info at which particular line your code hangs ?I mean another page code ?

Comment: @Suraj Singh Yeah, they are active using AJAX and i´m doing some requests. The code Hangs at active pages and inactive ones ( I mean, if I go to Default.aspx, and then open a new tab to go to Help.aspx, Help will hang the loading until Default had terminated the method TestaIntegracaoErpMigplus()). Maybe it´s something about sql connection pool? I dont know... Another pagecode that hangs is... wow, didn´t notice it before: it´s on another sqlConnection, but using the other database. I´m not using any kind of singleton approach, so, i´m actually lost here.

Comment: @Marciano.Andrade I do not have full confidence but may be enabling `MARS` may help you  `MultipleActiveResultSets=true;` .

Comment: @Suraj Singh I will try it, but the thing is: I´m using two diferent ConnectionStrings, and they use different connections, right? So why is one connection hanging another?

Comment: @Marciano.Andrade possibly it depends on db provider

Comment: I suspect it hangs because it's a static method, so all pages call that method. Within that method, connection pooling takes place & that probably has locks to ensure it's thread safe, so first call blocks all subsequent calls. You could switch connection pooling off as well which may stop it blocking all threads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you don't need to check for `ConnectionState`

If the connection cannot be opened [an exception is throw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.open.aspx)

Maybe this check is causing your issue

```
protected static bool TestaIntegracaoErpMigplus()
{
    bool ret = true;    

    try
    {
        string connectionStringMigplus = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringMigplus"].ConnectionString; 
        using (SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(connectionStringMigplus))
        {
            Conn.Open();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        ret = false;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

-------------UPDATE------------------

Try to lower the [connection timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in the connection string:

```
<add name="ConnectionStringMigplus" connectionString="Data Source=999.99.999.99;Initial Catalog=xxx;user=xxx;pwd=xxx;Connection Timeout=5" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: @Marciano.Andrade lower the connection timeout

Comment: Cant, because we have some expensive querys on that DB... or that´s just a timeout to CONNECT?

Comment: @Marciano.Andrade the time to wait while trying to establish a connection before terminating the attempt and generating an error.

Answer (score 4):

You can try move connection to [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and use [Wait](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd235606%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function with timeout, something like this

```
protected static bool TestaIntegracaoErpMigplus()
{
    string connectionStringMigplus = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringMigplus"].ConnectionString;
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(()=>{
        bool ret = true;
        using (SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(connectionStringMigplus))
        {
            try
            {
                Conn.Open();
            }
            catch (SqlException)
            {
                ret = false;
            }
        }

        return ret;
    });

    if(task.Wait(/*your timeout in milliseconds*/)){
        return task.Result;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: But it work just because I set the timeout, on the timeout time it still hangs the application... But it´s a nice workaround.

Comment: @Marciano.Andrade, yep, here you can specify only the maximum time it still hangs

Comment: This was a nice workaround, but I think that the other answer uses what was expected, a system way to lower the connect timeout method. Thank you very much!